# Joomla Category List display article image

Tags: joomla, web

In my main menu I have a category list. This works fine and dispays each article in the category.

However when i click the menu item and the category list shows there is just the name for each article, I want it to display an image for each article also. So in the article properties I set "intro image". This doesnt work.

How do  display an article image for every article displayed in the category list?

Comment: I've been looking into this and found an answer at this site:
http://www.byman.it/site/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46:joomla-image-in-category&catid=39:joomla&Itemid=101
Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with joomla extension "captifyContent"
http://www.joomlabamboo.com/joomla-extensions/captifycontent-beautiful-captions-for-your-content